# Jquery change triggers too often

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and got an on change event for a class like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.item_amount', function(){

});
```

Many selects on the same page have that class and if I change one of those selects the change event triggers X times if I change one of those selects(X is the amount of selects having that class) but I only want it to trigger once since only one select has changed.

Is that normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**

The problem seems to be somewhere else. The elements containing that select get inserted(Ajax call) and when one of them gets inserted into the dom, the change event is triggered for all existing elements.

So basically I got select number 1 which holds some products. When a product is selected HTML code is inserted into a div which holds all current products. When that happens the change event on all products in that div is triggered.

Comment: whether this code is in a loop

Comment: looks like the above code is executed many times possibly in a loop

Comment: Can't reproduce. Share test case.

Comment: Here is your code in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bic742/hk6Aa/2/) - the event is only triggered once for each change. Per @ArunPJohny, is it looping?

Comment: I made an edit to my question. I hope that helps to find the problem.

Comment: You need to post more code. Explaining the execution with no context won't help us solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [`this` keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) to refer to the current element changed in the change function block.

`this` --> JavaScript or Native Dom Element.

`$(this)` ->Your jQuery Object

```
$(document).on('change', '.item_amount', function(){
    alert(this.value);
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: That helped to find the real problem. I described it in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Set the. on change to the element and pass it as an argument to the function?